# How to mute scala/spark exceptions from pyspark/python

Tags: apache-spark, exception, pyspark, py4j

I want to silence the `parquet` file exceptions.  The `py4j` side of things was successfully muted by doing this:

```
                logging.getLogger('py4j').setLevel(CRITICAL)
                spark.read.parquet(in_path)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.getLogger('py4j').setLevel(WARN)
```

But then on the `jvm` side of things we still see the initial exception printed:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:476)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file:
```

How can the `jvm` side be suppressed as well?